# Postgres: inserting as many rows as a value on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to implement a ticket service of sorts, where each user has a certain number of tickets assigned to them. I have one table, users, that stores the name of the user and the number of tickets that will be assigned to them. But I have another table, tickets, that should have an entry for each ticket available with a foreign key that references its owner from the table users.

So, for example, if my table users contains:

| User_id | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ana | 3 |
| 2 | Mark | 4 |

I would like to have in my tickets table:

| ticket_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |

Where ticket_id is serial.

Is there a easy way to insert as many rows as the quantity indicates in users? I don't want to insert them all by hand...

Comment: You can use `generate_series`

Comment: Or you can use a recursive CTE. But `generate_series` is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done via Inner Join Lateral with generate_series.

```
Insert Into Tickets (user_id)
Select user_id
From Users Inner Join Lateral generate_series(1, Quantity) As t On true
Order by user_id
```